# Jetpack Compose - Disable / Hide system bar in deployed preview

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to disable the system bar on the deployed preview - anyone has a idea how to do this?

I currently call this on the activity to enable full screen mode.

```
fun Activity.enableFullscreenMode() {
    val windowInsetsController =
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
    windowInsetsController?.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}
```

Thank you!